# How to seed tables orderly to avoid "Integrity constraint violation" in Laravel 9.x

Tags: php, laravel, database, migrate, seed

I have a bookstore project, and have 2 table: `publishers` and `books`.
These is my two migrate file for books and publishers.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateBooksTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('available_quantity');
            $table->string('isbn');
            $table->string('language');
            $table->integer('total_pages');
            $table->float('price');
            $table->string('book_image');
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->date('published_date');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('publisher_id');
            $table->foreign('publisher_id')->references('id')->on('publishers');
            $table->unique('isbn');
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('books');
    }
}
```

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('publishers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('address');
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('publishers');
    }
};
```

As you see, `books` has a foreign key `publisher_id`, which has reference to `publishers` on `id`, so when I run `php artisan db:seed`,both tables will be seeded at the same time, but as we know, the `publishers` table should be seeded before `books` table be. So are there any way to seed tables orderly (not at the same time) ?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can actually create the related publisher when creating the books in a seeder.

```
// You can use the "for()" if you define it in a child table and "has()" when define in a parent table.

Book::factory(10)->for(Publisher::factory()->create())->create(); // will create 10 books but only belongs to one publisher

Publisher::factory(10)->has(Book::factory()->count(10))->create(); // will create 10 books in each publisher. it means that you will have a 100 books.
```

You can also directly define it in the `Database\Factories\BookFactory::class`

```
public function definition()
{
    return [
        'publisher_id' => Publisher::factory(), //add this to the BookFactory::class
    ];
}
```

```
Book::factory(10)->create(); // will create 10 book but also create 10 publisher
```

[Eloquent Factories: Factory Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-factories#factory-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer to make `Publisher` seeder first, then in set the value of `Book`'s `publisher_id` in the factory to be random from the existing `Publisher`.

1. Create 100 `Publisher`, or any amount you wish to set

   ```php
   Publisher::factory()->count(100)->create();
   ```
2. Ramdomly set `publisher_id` from the existing records

   ```php
   return [
      // ....
      'publisher_id' => Publisher::inRandomOrder()->first()->id
   ];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You have a file named DatabaseSeeder. You can choose the order of the seeder there:

```
public function run()
    {
        $this->call([
            PublisherSeeder::class,
            BookSeeder::class,
        ]);
    }
```

If you put PublisherSeeder first, the seeder will be called before BookSeeder and you won't have the constraint integretity error.